# Transform XML in Azure Logic Apps, upload C# Assembly (.DLL) file to Azure Integration Account and use it inside XSLT (map)

Tags: c#, azure, xslt, assemblies, azure-logic-apps

In Log Apps, I have a Source.xml file, which is required to be transformed into another destination.xml using XSLT. 
Within XSLT, I need to implement some custom logic using C# code which will be uploaded to  Azure Integration Account "Assemblies Section"

I have created one C# assembly file with StrongName but need to understand how the methods of C# assembly can be called from XSLT.

Would appreciate if anyone can share a working sample code with a very basic example.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example for your reference:

The c# code show as below:

```
using System;
namespace ExtAssembly
{
 public static class CalcFunctions
 {
 public static Int64 Add(Int64 a, Int64 b)
 {
 return a + b;
 }
 public static Int64 Subtract(Int64 a, Int64 b)
 {
 return a - b;
 }
 public static Int64 Multiply(Int64 a, Int64 b)
 {
 return a * b;
 }
 public static Double Divide(Int64 a, Int64 b)
 {
 return a / b;
 }
 }
}
```

And we can use the c# code in xslt as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform Jump " xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp Jump ">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="application/text" method="text" version="1.0" />
 <xsl:param name="MethodName" />
 <xsl:param name="Parameters" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:value-of select ="userCSharp:Invoke($MethodName, substring-before(substring-after($Parameters, '('), ')'))" />
 </xsl:template>
 <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp"> 
 <msxsl:assembly name="ExtAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
 <msxsl:using namespace="System.Reflection" />
 <msxsl:using namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
 <msxsl:using namespace="ExtAssembly" />
 <![CDATA[
 public object Invoke(string methodName, string methodParameters)
 {
 MatchCollection matches = new Regex("((?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\"(,|$)+)|(?<=,|^)[^,\"]*(?=,|$))").Matches(methodParameters); 
 ParameterInfo[] pars = typeof(CalcFunctions).GetMethod(methodName).GetParameters();
 object[] methodPars = new object[pars.Length]; 
 for (int i = 0; i < pars.Length; i++)
 {
 methodPars[i] = Convert.ChangeType(matches[i].Value, pars[i].ParameterType);
 }
 return typeof(CalcFunctions).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(null, methodPars);
 }
 ]]>
</msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After that, we can call it in our logic app(provide it wih "MethodName" and "Parameters" in "Transform xml" action).

For further information, you can refer to this [example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51493.azure-logic-app-calling-an-integration-account-assembly-function-from-within-an-app.aspx).

Hope it would be helpful to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Question is about how to use c# assembly with XSLT. 
Both XSLT AND C#  are being placed inside Azure Integration Account i.e in Maps and Assembly artifact sections respectively